How I can fillna value based on a different categorical column
I would like to fill the NaN values of column Partner_salary with 0 where Partner_working is 'No' and set the remaining NaN values with the mean of Partner_salary column.
pd.DataFrame({
    'Partner_working': ['Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No'],
    'Partner_salary': [np.NaN,np.NaN,1500,1000,0]})

I have tried to use the loc function to slice the data, but I am not able to continue to the next step
data.loc[data['Partner_salary'].isnull()==True,'Partner_working'].value_counts()

Output:
No 90,Yes 16


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please provide your code and desired output. The input needs to be provided as text, not a picture. You can use code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()). For more tips, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. See also How to ask a good question. You can [edit].

Please also provide some example data. Search similar questions (e.g. [pandas] fill conditional, they may give orientation to improve your question.

Beside the point, but ==True is redundant here

Where are you stuck exactly? This code doesn't use .fillna() or attempt to replace any values, so it's not clear what you need help with.

what is your exact desired output?

@Rishabh_KT way of appling a function might be easier to read.
If you want to stay with .loc logic, here is another way
# create example df
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Partner_working': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
    'Partner_salary': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 1500, 1000, 0]
})


# Update 'Partner_salary' to 0 where 'Partner_working' is "No"
df.loc[df['Partner_working'] == "No", 'Partner_salary'] = 0


# Calculate the mean of non-null 'Partner_salary'
mean = df['Partner_salary'].loc[~df['Partner_salary'].isnull()].mean()

# Fill NaN 'Partner_salary' with the mean
df['Partner_salary'].fillna(mean, inplace=True)




I would like to fill 'Partner_salary' as 0, where Partner_working is
No.

In that case you can write a function which returns zero if Partner_working is No and return Salary otherwise, and then use a lambda function to modify salary column
def f(Partner_working, Partner_salary):
    if Partner_working == 'No':
        return 0
    else:
        return Partner_salary

df['Partner_salary'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.Partner_working, x.Partner_salary), axis=1)

